# campo requerido si otro es diferente de null Angular

Tags: angular

Buen Dia para todos.

soy nuevo en el mundo de Angular y quisiera saber si es posible, hacer que un campo sea requerido solo si otro contiene datos.

Tengo un formulario con varios campos, la primera fila es obligatoria, pero de ahí en adelante deseo que cantidad y precio sean requeridos solamente si el campo producto contiene información.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi .ts especificamente quisiera que precio1 fuera requerido si producto 1 contiene informacion, supongo que debo crear mi propia validacion, pero me es dificil escribir esa validacion

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-facturas',
  templateUrl: './facturas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./facturas.component.css']
})
export class FacturasComponent implements OnInit {

  facturaForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.facturaForm = fb.group({
      factura: ['',Validators.required],
    producto: ['',Validators.required],
    producto1: ,
    producto2: ,
    producto3: ,
    producto4: ,
    cantidad: ['',Validators.required],
    cantidad1:
    cantidad2: ,
    cantidad3: ,
    cantidad4: ,
    precio: ['',Validators.required],
    precio1: ,
    precio2: ,
    precio3: ,
    precio4: ,
    pagada: ['',Validators.required]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

agradezco su colaboracion.

Comment: Esto puede servirte https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes escuchas los cambios en tu campo para revisar si tiene contenido y agregar la validación:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.formulario.get('campo').valueChanges.subscribe((valor) => {
      let campo_2 = this.formulario.get('campo_2');
      //Tiene un valor? - Quitamos espacios en blanco
      if (valor.trim().length > 0) campo_2.addValidators(Validators.required);
      //Si no hay valor, quitamos la validacion
      else campo_2.clearValidators();
      campo_2.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }

  formulario = new FormGroup({
    campo: new FormControl('', []),
    campo_2: new FormControl('', []),
  });

  enviar() {
    alert('Es valido??: ' + this.formulario.valid);
  }
```

Te dejo el ejemplo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bx41mj?file=src/app/app.component.ts):